# Error while running python script - bad operand type for unary +: 'str'

Tags: python

I get the following error when running a script:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "C:/Python27/PyInstaller-2.1/ketlc.py", line 354, in <module>
    startfun2(lk)

  File "C:/Python27/PyInstaller-2.1/ketlc.py", line 63, in startfun2
    vir_myurl =''' + '\'' + vi_myurl + '\'' + '''

TypeError: bad operand type for unary +: 'str'
```

This is the part of the code which seems to be causing trouble:

```
a_code = '''import os, time, webbrowser, pyHook, pythoncom, sys, logging, wget

import getpass, ctypes, random, inspect, autopy, ftplib, urllib

vi_host =''' + '\'' + vi_host + '\'' + '''

vi_logi =''' + '\'' + vi_logi + '\'' + '''

vi_pasi =''' + '\'' + vi_pasi + + '\'' + '''

vi_id =''' + '\'' + vi_vicid + '\'' + '''

vi_myurl =''' + '\'' + vi_myurl + '\'' + '''


nisa = 0 '''
```

I can't find anything wrong with it!
What should I do to fix it?

Comment: `vi_pasi =''' + '\'' + vi_pasi + + '\'' + ''' ` has 2 subsequent `+` signs.

Comment: I spotted you have two + operators here: `''' + '\'' + vi_pasi + + '\'' + '''`

Comment: You should get an IDE with syntax highlighting so you can spot these things. Also, whatever you're trying to do with all this concatenation of what is apparently source code (to be executed later) is almost certainly a bad idea that you should avoid, finding another way to accomplish whatever it is you're doing.

Answer (score 0):

Check the quote count and backslashes.

`File "C:/Python27/PyInstaller-2.1/ketlc.py", line 63, in startfun2
    vir_myurl =''' + '\'' + vi_myurl + '\'' + '''`

You're using the *string* `vi_myurl`, not the *variable* `vi_myurl`. If you want those backslashes in there, they also need to be escaped with an additional backslash.

As mentioned above, syntax highlighting is extremely helpful for spotting these errors.